# cannot resolvewebsphere exception

Tags: java, websphere

How to resolve this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=org/apache/axis/client/Service, méthod=getPort(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;, pc=0
```

Comment: More information is needed to answer your question.  What version of WebSphere app server are you using?  What are you doing when the verify error occurs.  What other errors are present in logs?

Answer (score 1):

There maybe jar conflicts.
One possible solution is you can turn off the bytecodes checking by adding the following to your JVM initialization params

```
-Xverify:none
```

For more help, you can refer to :[FileNet P8 Content Engine event action code fails with class loading constraint violation.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21619489)

Comment: thx it works, but i wonder if this conf will caue any problem in production environnement..